# Addresses field in ScriptPubkey

Tags: transactions, address, script

```
"txid": "055f9c6dc094cf21fa224e1eb4a54ee3cc44ae9daa8aa47f98df5c73c48997f9",
"hash": "055f9c6dc094cf21fa224e1eb4a54ee3cc44ae9daa8aa47f98df5c73c48997f9",
"version": 1,
"size": 433,
"vsize": 433,
"locktime": 0,
"vin": [
    {
        "txid": "b187426f2fdd5a7ac2f49d822f68e07f48486ee53a8a45de2494f12acb37a0d8",
        "vout": 3,
        "scriptSig": {
            "asm": "3046022100d78c31a20fa11533475be893b229eb4d252e600dcc2a0735d360c541b6aec813022100e3eaa72c915ef47d94ccbd18c2ba6d9ae5b98be6e9fbf968d4bbbb003e06d687[ALL] 030e001332b43924be343986cca3df669f57b0dedd120990e727787f8dea50fdbc",
            "hex": "493046022100d78c31a20fa11533475be893b229eb4d252e600dcc2a0735d360c541b6aec813022100e3eaa72c915ef47d94ccbd18c2ba6d9ae5b98be6e9fbf968d4bbbb003e06d6870121030e001332b43924be343986cca3df669f57b0dedd120990e727787f8dea50fdbc"
        },
        "sequence": 4294967295
    }
],
"vout": [
    {
        "value": 0.00010860,
        "n": 0,
        "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "1 030e001332b43924be343986cca3df669f57b0dedd120990e727787f8dea50fdbc 20434e545250525459000000140001a9e0e85838b5000000174876e800010053b6 2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG",
            "hex": "5121030e001332b43924be343986cca3df669f57b0dedd120990e727787f8dea50fdbc2120434e545250525459000000140001a9e0e85838b5000000174876e800010053b652ae",
            "reqSigs": 1,
            "type": "multisig",
            "addresses": [
                "1FrbMcddiM1v3HMpUqygjZYCamBykWCWao"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "value": 0.00010860,
        "n": 1,
        "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "1 030e001332b43924be343986cca3df669f57b0dedd120990e727787f8dea50fdbc 20a3c3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG",
            "hex": "5121030e001332b43924be343986cca3df669f57b0dedd120990e727787f8dea50fdbc2120a3c300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000052ae",
            "reqSigs": 1,
            "type": "multisig",
            "addresses": [
                "1FrbMcddiM1v3HMpUqygjZYCamBykWCWao"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "value": 0.00010860,
        "n": 2,
        "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "1 030e001332b43924be343986cca3df669f57b0dedd120990e727787f8dea50fdbc 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG",
            "hex": "5121030e001332b43924be343986cca3df669f57b0dedd120990e727787f8dea50fdbc2110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000052ae",
            "reqSigs": 1,
            "type": "multisig",
            "addresses": [
                "1FrbMcddiM1v3HMpUqygjZYCamBykWCWao"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "value": 0.01061564,
        "n": 3,
        "scriptPubKey": {
            "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 a2f2d251cc06ec1e789800127e3fa6ed9e515651 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
            "hex": "76a914a2f2d251cc06ec1e789800127e3fa6ed9e51565188ac",
            "reqSigs": 1,
            "type": "pubkeyhash",
            "addresses": [
                "1FrbMcddiM1v3HMpUqygjZYCamBykWCWao"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

In the above transaction, each scriptpubkey has `addresses` array and it  has 1 address. I guess this address is derived from the `public key` of `asm`. In this example each `asm` has 2 public keys. So addresses array should contain 2 addresses. But it has only one. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look to https://blockchain.info/tx/055f9c6dc094cf21fa224e1eb4a54ee3cc44ae9daa8aa47f98df5c73c48997f9?show_adv=true

At the bottom of the page you can see "disassembled" output scripts. Yes, outputs 0, 1 and 2 have the form of `1 pushdata33 pushdata33 2 CHECKMULTISIG` so these outputs are 1-of-2 multisig outputs. But you should look even deeper! The compressed form of public key is 33 bytes long and must start with `02` or `03` in hex representation. What do you see on that page? The lines

```
20434e545250525459000000140001a9e0e85838b5000000174876e800010053b6
20a3c3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

do not start with `02` or `03` so they are not public keys. It may be some garbage or another protocol layer like a counterparty. I do not know.

The modern Bitcoin Core client does not try to convert these chunks of bytes to a public keys and does not try to create human readable addresses. So, you see only one address `1FrbMcddiM1v3HMpUqygjZYCamBykWCWao` in console. This is not a bug, this is a feature.